# Parse data structures clang/LLVM

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I was wondering what is the best solution in order to parse and obtain data structures from C sources files. Suppose that I have:

```
typedef int M_Int;
typedef float* P_Float;

typedef struct Foo {
  M_Int a;
  P_Float p_f;
} Foo;
```

What is the best way to unfold the data structures in order to get the primitives of both variables `a` and `p_f` of struct `Foo`?

Parsing the AST, for very simple examples, could be the best way, but when the code becomes more complex, maybe it's better to work in a more low-level way with IR code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use llvm debug info to grab the information you need. If you compile the C code with `-g` option, it generates debug info which contains all the information. Understanding llvm debuginfo is tricky mostly because there is not much documentation about their structure and how to access them. Here are some links:

1) http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html

2) Here is a link to a project that I am working on which uses debug info. This might not be too useful as there is not much documentation but it might be useful to see the usage of the debuginfo classes. We are trying to get field names for all pointer parameters (including field names in case of structure parameter) of a C function. All of the code related to debuginfo access is in this file: https://github.com/jiten-thakkar/DataStructureAnalysis/blob/dsa_llvm3.8/lib/dsaGenerator/DSAGenerator.cpp

Answer (score 0):

To find the underlying types, the AST is a good level to work at. Clang can  automate and scale this process with AST Matchers and Callbacks, used in conjunction with libtooling. For example, the AST matcher combination

```
fieldDecl( hasType( tyoedefType().bind("typedef") ) ).bind("field")
```

will match fields in C structs that are declared with a typedef instead of a built-in type. The `bind()` calls make AST nodes accessible to a Callback. Here's a Callback whose `run()` method gets the underlying type of the field declaration:

```
virtual void run(clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder::MatchResult const & result) override
{
  using namespace clang;
  FieldDecl * f_decl =
      const_cast<FieldDecl *>(result.Nodes.getNodeAs<FieldDecl>("field"));
  TypedefType * tt = const_cast<TypedefType *>(
      result.Nodes.getNodeAs<TypedefType>("typedef"));
  if(f_decl && tt) {
    QualType ut = tt->getDecl()->getUnderlyingType();
    TypedefNameDecl * tnd = tt->getDecl();

    std::string struct_name = f_decl->getParent()->getNameAsString();
    std::string fld_name = f_decl->getNameAsString();
    std::string ut_name = ut.getAsString();
    std::string tnd_name = tnd->getNameAsString();

    std::cout << "Struct '" << struct_name << "' declares field '"
              << fld_name << " with typedef name = '" << tnd_name << "'"
              << ", underlying type = '" << ut_name << "'" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    // error handling
  }
  return;
}  // run
```

Once this is put into a Clang Tool and built, running

```
typedef-report Foo.h --   # Note two dashes
```

produces

```
Struct 'Foo' declares field 'a' with typedef name = 'M_Int', underlying type = 'int'
Struct 'Foo' declares field 'p_f' with typedef name = 'P_Float', underlying type = 'float *'
```

I put up a full working example app in a [Code Analysis and Refactoring Examples with Clang Tools project](https://github.com/lanl/CoARCT) (see  apps/TypedefFinder.cc).